# Show Duplicate GPS point from CSV file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps, csv

I want to load a `*.csv` file containing GPS data into QGIS. In my file, there are some duplicate coordinates (two different people living in same household). And I want them to show as two points because they represent two different people. But QGIS only shows one point and ignores the other one.

Do you have any solution for this issue?

I think maybe creating different `.csv` file (to separate duplicate data) might solve this issue but I haven't tried it yet and it's not good solution because I have a lot of GPS data.

Comment: can you post an example of your csv file?

Answer (score 1):

Your duplicate points appear as one point in QGIS as they are on top of each other.
for verification, open the attribute table of your layer and order the records by longitude or by latitude and you will see the duplicates still exist.

Answer (score 1):

If yo're importing a CSV where each row has a coordinate, QGIS doesn't "Ignore", them, rather they are displayed one on top of the other.

If you want to manually move the overlapping features, you can use the Points Displacement tool, which lets you set a certain displacement distance for all features in a point layer. When used in cojunction with a selection, you can create a new layer with just the overlapping points displaced, but you'de have to edit your question to be more detailed in the required result and useage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you imported the *.csv file as layer into QGIS, right click on the layer > properties > style
Change it into "Point Displacement"
[image: Layer Properties]